# JavaFx: ListView remove last item(s) bug?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8, selection

I found an issue, I am not sure if it is a bug or a feature, but I would like to get an answer and an elegant solution for the following problem:

I have a `ListView` with `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE` and I have a button which removes the selected items from the listview. The problem is after I remove the last element, the list `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` is empty while `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` is **not** `null`. 
This happens only if I remove the last element, or the last elements in a range from the listView.

My java version is 8u121.

Does anybody know  this issue? It is a feature or a bug? 
Is there any proper solution to this?

My purpose to handle the enabled/disabled status of a button, depending of a property of the selectedItems.

Here  is a simple example where you can check it:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public ListView<Model> listView;
    @FXML
    public Button button;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        initListView();
        button.setOnAction(event -> listView.getItems().removeAll(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null);
            System.out.println(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty());
        });
    }

    private void initListView() {
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Model("Test"));

    }

    private class Model {

        private StringProperty test;

        public Model(String test) {
            this.test = new SimpleStringProperty(test);
        }

        public String getTest() {
            return test.get();
        }

        public StringProperty testProperty() {
            return test;
        }
    }

}
```

The `View.fxml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="stackoverflow.three.Controller">
    <ListView fx:id="listView"/>
    <Button fx:id="button" text="Remove"/>
</VBox>
```

The `Main` class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
        VBox pane = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` is not `null`. What is it?

Comment: I don't see a problem.

Comment: When I delete the last item, the item above it is automatically selected.

Comment: When I delete the last item and the `ListView` is empty, it shows both are empty.

Comment: @NathanNorman the previous item in the `ListView`

Comment: What version of Java are you using? There have been numerous bugs in this area, some fixed in later versions of Java 8, some only in Java 9.

Comment: @Sedrick Yes it is  selected, but the list of `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` doesn't contain that item, it is empty, but if there is a selected item, it should appear in the list.

Comment: java8u121, I will mention in the question as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, even on the same JDK version. Are you sure this is the exact code you are running? Can you create a complete example using this code (i.e. post the FXML and application class) so that we can test the exact same thing you are running?

Comment: If you are using multiple selection mode, it really makes more sense to use the list of selected items anyway. So you would just do `button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));`

Comment: I have edited the question with the missing parts of the test app. I have  just tried also your suggestion, but I my disable is a little bit more  complex, I need information about the selected items, so I just cannot use that way, and when I get the selected items it is empty after a  remove. After you remove an item, those two sysouts why print two different  values, they should be the same, or do I misunderstand  something?

Comment: Today I have tested this issue at `TableView` and it worked as I expect. I think the ListView has this bug, I  could write a workaround for it but it is a workaround so not the best way to solve.